# mysql - return the entire table + count another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a forum for a school project and I'm trying to come up with a query that will give me all the forum names + count how many posts there are for each forum.

The idea is simple: one table holds a list of all the forums (forum id, forum name, forum description) and another table holds all the topics (topic id, forum id (the forum that it belongs to), topic title).
What I need is an sql query that will do a select * from forums AND also add another column for how many records there are in the topics table that correspond to the particular forum id.

My forums structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forums` (
  `forum_id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `forum_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `forum_description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`forum_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `forum_name` (`forum_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

My topics structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `topics` (
  `topic_id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topic_forum_id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `topic_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`topic_id`),
  KEY `topic_forum_id` (`topic_forum_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any homework you did before you post?

Comment: This is a pretty basic SQL query with a `join` and `group by`.  You should be able to figure it out yourself.

Comment: This question does not show any effort on solving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking something as below -

```
select `forums`.*, count(`topics`.`topic_id`) as `tot_topic`
from `forums`
left join `topics` on `topics`.`topic_forum_id` = `forums`.`forum_id`
group by `forums`.`forum_id`
```

Check here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74852/2